# What should I do with this Latex Error when I use sublime3 to build in Ubuntu?

Tags: fonts, xetex, pdftex, sublime-text

I want to use LaTeX on Ubuntu 16.04 and I have installed texlive2017, sublimeText3 and the sublime plugin: `latexTools`. But when I create a new file, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to select "`Latex-pdfLatex`" and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to build the file, it throws me an error which is :

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/fontset/ctex-fontset-fandol.def:109: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! [  }]

pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file cyberb65): Font cyberb65 at 723 not found
Check the TeX log file for more information
```

and here is my configuration in `LatexTools.sublime.settings`:

```
"linux" : {
// Path used when invoking tex & friends; MUST include $PATH
"texpath" : "$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux",
// Command to invoke Python. Useful if you have Python installed in a
// non-standard location or want to use a particular version of python.
// Both Python2 and Python3 are supported, but must have the DBus bindings
// installed.
"python": "/usr/bin/Python3",
// The name of the ST2 or ST3 executable. On Ubuntu, both subl and sublime-text are
// available for ST2; adjust as needed for other platforms, and for ST3
"sublime": "sublime-text",
// How long to wait after evince or okular has launched before sending a sync message
// in seconds, floating point; choose 2.0 or 3.0 on a slower machine, 0.5 on a fast one
// Note: only tweak this if sync after launching the PDF viewer does not seem to work,
// or if the PDF viewer opens instantly and you don't want to wait.
// Default: 1.5 (works on my MBP4,1...)
"sync_wait": 0.5,
// Command to invoke Sublime Text. Used if the keep_focus toggle is true.
// If blank, "subl" or "sublime_text" will be used.
"sublime_executable": "",
// how long (in ms) to wait after the jump_to_pdf command completes
// before switching focus back to Sublime Text. This may need to be
// adjusted depending on your machine and configuration.
"keep_focus_delay": 0.5
},
```

In addition, when I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to set "`Latex-XeLatex`" and then build the file, it did not throw errors but there was no pdf file created.

I also installed `dbus`, but it seems that it did not work.

Does it mean I need to install some fonts? What should I do now to build the file and get a pdf file?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I have solved this problem by changing my first line from `\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}` to `\documentclass{article}`.
It seems that the sublime throw the error because of lacking something to support Chinese characters.

Comment: None of those errors are sublime errors. Your latex installation is missing fonts. Exactly which latex did you install? Upstream or the Ubuntu one?